# AngularJS ng-include is not working in UI Bootstrap

Tags: angular-ui-bootstrap

I am very new to AngularJS. I have read several posts on this topic, but am still unable to get data loaded via ng-include

Here is my html and js code

js

```
.controller('TabsDemoCtrl', function ($scope, $window) {
    $scope.tabs = [
        {
            title:'Home',
            content:"test.html"
        },
        {
            title:'Profile',
            content:"test.html"
        },
        {
            title:'Messages',
            content:"test.html"
        },
        {
            title:'Settings',
            content:"test.html"
        }
    ];
})
```

html

```
<div class="card-body card-padding" data-ng-controller="TabsDemoCtrl">
        <tabset vertical="true">
            <tab ng-repeat="tab in tabs" heading="{{tab.title}}" active="tab.active" disable="tab.disabled">
                <div ng-include="tab.content"></div>
            </tab>
        </tabset>
    </div>
```

test.html

```
<h1>This is html file</h1>
```

I don't know what is the issue and why test.html is not being loaded. Can anyone please help me to find out the issue?

Comment: have you tried ng-include="'test.html'"?

Comment: yeah! I already tried that.

Comment: test.html is in the same folder, or is it in like "partials/test.html"?  Also, I don't see an "ng-controller" tag.  "ng-controller="TabsDemoCtrl as tab"  Is that in index, and you're calling from like home or something?  Or is this your "index" file?  if it is, you need the ng-controller so it knows where to go.

Comment: I edited html code for ng-controller. and I don't know where I should locate test.html

Comment: I would download a functional skeleton from github, and look at the files.  Here's a starting point, I have never used this guy, but he was the first result for an "angular github" search, so it probably has a lot of hits...https://github.com/johnpapa/ng-demos